# Verifying Linkedin company URL through the development portal

Tags: spring-boot, linkedin-api

Whenever i try to verify a company's url in linkedin through the development portal.  run into "Unauthorized Request
You are not authorized to verify this app"
Has anyone ran into this issue and how did they solve it?

I used the url provided to me and it took me to a page like what is below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z46oH.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.